# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'idlelib'

Tags: python, idle

I am trying to use **IDLE** but am experience this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'idlelib'
```

I have tried to remove and reinstall IDLE but it doesn't seem to work either. I am currently running **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** and am running off of a Nvidia Jetson TX2. My `python3 -V` is 3.7.3.

Any assistance or answers would be helpful.

Here is the output of `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` and `locate "idlelib/__init__.py"`

```
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-aarch64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0']
```

Comment: Odd, there is no idlelib. See with `python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` and `sudo updatedb; locate "idlelib/__init__.py"`

Comment: How did you install python3, using apt or from source ?

Comment: I don't have this problem running idle on 18.04. Did you install idle through `apt`? Also, instead of running `idle` have you tried running the command: `idle-python3.6`?

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue.

I installed Tk and idle3 and my issue was resolved

Install Tk

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Install idle3

```
sudo apt-get install idle3
```

Comment: It works on Ubuntu 22.04 also.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the package for your python version (for python 3.8 it's "idle-python3.8"):

```
sudo apt install deb-package-name
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install idle-python3.x

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the same issue in my Ubuntu 16.04 OS while using idle3. I have python3.6.10 version in my system. But when I entered idle-python3.6 instead of idle3, the IDE got opened without any issues.